# How to fix error with negative input in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a lab for coding class and I'm having an error when I try to use a negative number as my input for distance.

It will run with a positive distance but I cannot get it run a negative one.

```
function [Angle] = aim(V0,Target)

dt=0.01; 
Theta=30;
j=1;
for b=1:0.5:360 
    T(j)=missile(V0,b);
    j=1+j; 
end

[dist]=max(T);
if dist < Target
    error('Out of Range')
else 
    cx=3;
    while cx > 2
        Dist= missile(V0,Theta);
        Theta2=Theta+dt;   
        Dist2= missile(V0,Theta2);
        dx=abs(Dist-Dist2);    
        cx=Dist-Target;   
        Theta= Theta - (cx/(dx/dt));
    end
end

Angle=(Theta);
end
```

Comment: Why would you want a negative one in the first place? A negativ distance does not make much sense physically, right?

Comment: What mean `missile` in this context? You didn't declared it anywhere.

Comment: Please see [mcve]. We cannot run your code, so we cannot say what is wrong with it. Do include also an example where you show how you call your function with a negative distance, and the error you get.